# c++ simple pointer program

Tags: c++, pointers, atoi

Here is a simple program where it sums all of the numbers sent in on the command line.  It should take an arbitrary number of values.
It keeps giving me a 0 for each line. I've tired to make several changes but it continues to give the same output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
     int sum=0;
     sum+=atoi("argc[i]");
     cout << sum << endl;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: book says nothing about this. im not an idiot posting here was my last option

Comment: Change `atoi("argc[i]");` to `atoi(argc[i]);`

Comment: @caustr01 Thats not true at all, this is an extremely simple problem that really any google search would have explained if you looked up the syntax of C++ such as, how to use the atoi function and which variable in main() gives the command line options (argv in this case).

Comment: If the book says nothing, it may be because you did not understood it. You really need dozen hours of work and reading.

Comment: @avt nope. Nope nope nope.

Comment: I wonder when a solution that doesn't use `atoi` will appear.

Comment: You should start your loop at `int i = 1`, because `argv[0]` usually holds the name of the program that is invoked instead of the first parameter that is passed via command line.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that was unnecessary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows minimal or no understanding on the part of the asker.

Comment: There was maybe two pages on pointers and I looked thru trying to find atoi but couldn't so I googled everything I could think of on atoi, pointers, using sum I just couldn't find the answer I was looking for. I am extremely new to c++ and my teacher does not explain anything well.  I have a very busy life family/military/school that spending hours looking for the answer to a small program would be a waste. I spent the time  i could trying to find the answer myself and changed my program several times before coming here for help so please stop bashing me.

Answer (score 3):

`"argc[i]"` is a *literal string* so when converted by `atoi` gives 0! `sum` should be initialized before the loop :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int sum=0;
 for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
   sum += atoi(argv[i]);
 } 
 cout << sum << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Conventionally `argv[0]` is the name of the program (or at least the name used in the command line to invoke the program), so better start at index 1.

You need to **spend dozen of hours reading more your books and experimenting on your computer**. Asking here such a basic question don't help you at all (and is considered as rude...).

Don't forget to **enable debugging info and all warnings when compiling** (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then, learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: That did it thank you so much! And for being polite about.

Answer (score -1):

Your basics are not clear, I suggest you to read the book.
Program should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sum=0;
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
   {

     sum+=atoi(argv[i]);
   }
   cout << sum << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now if you format the code properly it doesn't add nothing to @Basile's answer.

Answer (score -4):

move parameter sum outside loop!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {

     sum+=atoi(argv[i]);
     cout << sum << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix anything really.

Comment: i tried that as well and it says sum is not declared in this scope which is why i kept it inside the for loop

Comment: updated example -> argv[i]

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : You are right, I was quick in response. When I did see the sum variabele in the loop, I made the assumption that the rest was correct. My bad.. Assumption is the mother of all failures